# Switch case in SQL 2008 Server R2

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been trying to create a search function on a webpage / form. It's a bit complicated since it has multiple search boxes.

It has to search the sql database and return the right row(s).

I was looking for a switch equivalent to execute a certain query if a value is null or not. typically if the user doesn't enter the student ID (primary key) then it will go the queries that doesn't include the ID parameter. Not sure if it's the right logic. My knowledge in sql is quite limited atm, sorry if it's a basic question but i didn't find a solution on google since apparently nobody ever needed to do this. I'm looking a stored procedure of  course

Here's what I'm thinking of firing into a SQL

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Student_CRUD"))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SEARCH");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", StudentID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Class);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RollNumber", RollNumber);
    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException exp)
    {
        Response.Write(exp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `Student_CRUD` proc definition as well?

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) may be what you needed to find (it may be a bit wordy to start with but hopefully you can look at the examples and see how they generally work)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the query inside the stored procedure:

```
WHERE FirstName = @FirstName 
  AND (@StudentID IS NULL OR (StudentID = @StudentID))
  AND (@Class NULL OR (Class = @Class))
  ....
```

But, you have to set the `@studentID` value to null (`DBNull.Value`) in your code, so that the `null` value will be passed to the sql query. So when passing a null value to this query, the condition will be ignored.

Comment: This sounds promising, can I chain those ANDs? I could get it done pretty easily if that'd work.